# Git .gitignore Commands

Tags: git, gitignore

I am reading the official GIT manual. However, I am finding that some things are not being ignored in my **.gitignore** file. For instance:

The GIT manual says, "*You can end patterns with a forward slash (/) to specify a directory.*"
*You can start patterns with a forward slash (/) to avoid recursively*

As it stands, I have a directory in the same directory where the .gitignore file is located. I also have a directory entitled 'test'. Test has several sub-dirs and the last directory has a text file. The full path is **test/matt/end/matt.txt**

I only have one command in the **.gitignore** file. For testing I am substituting to versions of it:

When I use the following:

**/test** - It ignores the entire path including the matt.txt file. When I try:
**test/** - It does the same exact thing.

The GIT manual also says the following, "*only ignore the TODO file in the current directory, not subdir /TODO:
/TODO*"

Can someone please explain this to me please? Could the manual be wrong?

---

I created a new git repository on Linux. You will see everything in the screen shot.

In the .gitignore file I have tried it both ways /matt and matt/ Take a look at the screen shot here [.gitignore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JORI.jpg). Based on the GIT manual, it shouldn't be working this way.

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: `test/` would also cause something like `foo/test/mat/end/matt.txt` to be ignored; the leading `/` is used to anchor the match to the top of the repository.

Comment: By any chance, are some of the file that you're quoting already tracked (added once with `git add` then committed) ? If so, they'll keep on being followed regardless of .gitignore file.

Comment: I actually marked them files as unknow by using git rm -r --cached , in order to test the .gitignore file.

Comment: In order for this to work, do the files need to be untracked? Because I added them to staging and nothing I put in .gitignore works.

Comment: Ok. I understand it only works for untracked files. Of course, when you're log files are generated they are untracked and you don't want to save them.

Comment: But here is my issue: With this directory here test/matt/end/matt.txt if I put /end in my .gitignore, it still ignores everything from the parent directory test down to end.

Comment: Unclear what you think is wrong with what Git is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confused about what **recursive** means here. In this context, if you write

```
/test
```

It will not ignore any subdirectories named test. If you instead write

```
test/
```

all subfolders named test will be ignored as well.

### Example

I created a repository with the following files:

```
new file:   .gitattributes
new file:   .gitignore
new file:   aFolder/test/New Text Document.txt
new file:   test/New Text Document.txt
```

If add `/test` to my .gitignore file:

```
new file:   .gitattributes
new file:   .gitignore
new file:   aFolder/test/New Text Document.txt
```

Notice git doesn't recurse for the `test` directory. It only ignored top-level directories named `test`. If instead I add `test/`:

```
new file:   .gitattributes
new file:   .gitignore
```

Now, it ignores any file that is contained within a `test` directory, regardless of the depth of that directory.

Comment: With this directory here test/matt/end/matt.txt if I put /end in my .gitignore, it still ignores everything from the parent directory test down to end.

Comment: @MattPaolini is test/ or /test still in your .gitignore file? Have you already made commits? I do not see the same result on my end.

Comment: I changed all of my files to be untracked. So, the .gitignore commands are working, I just don't know why it's ignoring the entire root and sub directories. The commands aren't working they way they describe in the manual or other sources I've checked.

Comment: I am going to set up a fresh repo and create it like Kraigolas did. I will let you know.

Comment: I created a new repo. New .gitignore file and I am still having the same problems. Would it help if I posted my git config? If so, how would I post it in a comment?

Comment: @MattPaolini As you are OP, it might be more helpful if you simply edit your post with the configuration files at the bottom.